# XPATH (again) optional tag element extract single string

Tags: python, xpath, browser

I have a list of these `<TD>`s and am using a list comprehension to get them all at once.
Looking to extract the text "v 11/4" in both cases, ie with/without the sup
Must be extracted into a single element (for this row).

ex 1

```
<td>
<b class="black">2</b>/6 <a href="/some/link"onclick=
"returnHtml.popup(this," title="whateveryoulike">(ABL TTTTTSSSSSS
11)</a>v 11/4</td>
```

ex 2

```
<td>
<b class="black">2</b>/6 <a href="/some/link"onclick=
"returnHtml.popup(this," title="whateveryoulike">(ABL TTTTTSSSSSS
11)</a>v<sup>1</sup> 11/4</td>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you use to execute the XPath, `lxml`, scrapy, selenium, something else?

Comment: scrapy - problem solved

Comment: easy for anon users to come and mark posts down. Come on, show your faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to identify text "v 11/4" which consistent for both `<td>` examples would be *'concatenation of all direct child text nodes (of `<td>`) which located after `<a>`'*. Below is example implementation using `lxml.html` :

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> raw = '''<tr>
... <td>
... <b class="black">2</b>/6 <a href="/some/link" onclick=
... "returnHtml.popup(this," title="whateveryoulike">(ABL TTTTTSSSSSS
... 11)</a>v 11/4</td>
... <td>
... <b class="black">2</b>/6 <a href="/some/link" onclick=
... "returnHtml.popup(this," title="whateveryoulike">(ABL TTTTTSSSSSS
... 11)</a>v<sup>1</sup> 11/4</td>
... </tr>'''
... 
>>> root = html.fromstring(raw)
>>> result = [''.join(txt for txt in td.xpath("a/following-sibling::text()")).strip() \
...             for td in root.xpath("//td")]
... 
>>> result
['v 11/4', 'v 11/4']
```